# Using functional Principal components to make predictions

Tags: python, functional-programming, pca

I would like to use FPCA to reconstruct a partial curve.

I have 20 temperature curves and each curve contains 365 days. I would like to do FPCA on 15 curves and extract functional PCA. The other 5 curves only have data up to 100 days. I would like to use the extracted PCA to make prediction and reconstruct the 5 curves to 365 days. How can I do that in python?

The code I have so far is fitting FPCA, but how do I do the prediction?

```
    train_grid = FDataGrid(data_matrix=training_data, grid_points=day[:365])
    test_grid = FDataGrid(data_matrix=testing_data, grid_points=day[:100])

    fpca = FPCA(n_components=2)
    fpca.fit(train_grid)
    train_scores = fpca.transform(train_grid)
    test_scores = fpca.transform(test_grid)
    y_pred = fpca.inverse_transform(test_scores)
```

It gave me error ValueError: Incorrect dimension in data_matrix and grid_points.

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: it is using python

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.